# How to configure in app purchases in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want to have a premium section in my app, where only users who have paid for some price can view it.

I want to charge users every month for the premium section, please how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an official documentation for it :

You can check it :

[in_app_purchase 0.3.4+8](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase)